# Query object only if child has particular attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a few models defined as follows:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skill_tags, as: :skillable
end

class SkillTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skillable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :skill
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skill_tags
end
```

I want to get an array of all Question objects with a particular skill associated with them.

For example - I want all questions that have a skill tag with a skill_id of 16, 34, and 89. These could be in an array. What's the most Rails-friendly way of achieving this? I can think of some more 'brute-force' approaches, but I'd like it to be as clean as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Question.joins(:skill_tag).where(:skill_tags => {:skill_id => [16, 34, 89]})
```

Answer (score 4):

Further to the excellent SQL-based approach by SlicedPan, you should also look at using something like a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skill_tags, as: :skillable
  scope :tags(ids)-> { joins(:skill_tags).where("skill_tags.skill_id = ?", ids) }
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
tags = [16, 17, 18]
@questions = Question.tags(tags)
```

Comment: I really like this approach - I'm going with Slicedpan's for the moment, but I'll definitely be looking into implementing your example on a broader scale. Thanks!

Comment: Scopes are greater for writing DRY code, if you find yourself using this functionality in many different places then you should put it in a scope as above